# Cannot find type 'NSViewRepresentable' in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsviewrepresentable

I want to create a blurred view in SwiftUI using NSViewRepresentable but XCode gives me an error message that says "Cannot find type 'NSViewRepresentable' in scope".

```
import SwiftUI

struct BlurWindow: NSViewRepresentable { //Cannot find type 'NSViewRepresentable' in scope

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView { //Cannot find type 'Context' in scope

        let view = NSVisualEffectView() //Cannot find type 'NSVisualEffectView' in scope
        view.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) { //Cannot find type 'Context' in scope

    }
}
```

However, when I copied and pasted this exact same code into a new brand new Xcode project, there are no errors. I searched all over Google and StackOverflow and haven't found anyone with the same issue.

Comment: What's the target of you project? NSViewRepresentable is only for macOS, and only from 10.15.

Comment: @Asperi the target is iOS. I fixed it by deselecting iOS under Target Membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your project have an iOS target? Are you building that target? If so, make sure the file is not included in this target(using the file inspector under Target Membership) since NSViewRepresentable is not available on iOS.

Alternatively you can wrap your code in `#if os(macOS)` and `#endif`.